# OAuth client id and secret handling

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I know this question has been asked before, but i cannot find any good answers to this. I am developing an OAuth solution, and we are using resource owner flow for our own native application.

The client id and secret is what we use to know its an "official" request, but what is stopping anyone from finding the Client Id and secret on the client and implement the same. How can we properly secure the client id and secret, so only our official applications can use them.

What is the best practice for this, and is it even possible to stop this. I assume anything that is stored on the client can in some way be reversed and someone can pretend to be a "native" app.

I assume Facebook are using resource owner flow for their own applications. How do they protect their client id and client secret? The token they receives probably has permissions for anything and probably also some internal API's, so i believe they don't want everyone to be able to use that.

Comment: There is no true way to stop hacking/impersonation/sniffing, whilst some tricks make it a little more difficult, even the giants(Google,Microsoft,NHS) are hacked every other month. I personally always use SSL, I then HMAC and use other encryption process's when passing over the wire. I expire my tokens, I regularly change my resource owner tokens (app to app communication). Hopefully you'll get a good answer, because I'm also interested.

Comment: You can't secure a client secret: always assume anything the client knows is public knowledge. Which leads to the question of what you are using the client secret for? You're using ResourceOwnerPassword flow, so the security comes from the identity credentials of the user using your client, not the client itself. Once a user has identified (authenticated) themself, then your authorisation should be based on what that user can do - not what that client can do.

Comment: Well i agree for the most part, what you have on the client is public knowledge. That is why i wonder what people usually do to prevent "impersonation", since client permissions are different. If someone can just "pretend" to be me then the point of using scopes, clients and consent is not really doing anything, other than being convenient for your partners that integrate into your solution.